# jQuery image slide that does not stretch images

Tags: jquery, html, image, web, aspect-ratio

I am looking for a jQuery image slider.  The issue with the popular Nivo Slider is that it stretches the images to fit the width of the slider.  I am looking for a slider that does not do that.  I also have a max-width and max-height I want these images to display.  I am not hardcoding height\width as I would like to preserve the aspect ratio.

For example:

Let's say I have my slider in a div that is 1000x500 and an image that is 1500 X 1000 px.  Assuming the max-height is 1000 and the max-width is 500, the image will be displayed as a 750x500px image.  I would like the slider to work like this, centering the smaller image in the div, as opposed to stretching my image.

Anyone know of such a plugin?  Upvotes all around to those who do.

Comment: well if your images are of SAME size and you know what it is then you just set a max-width on the images inside of your current slider and text-align center on the container. If the images are different sizes then you will need some js work to get the correct width then apply it as max-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with nivo-slider 3, I resolved this issue on iphone by putting a fixed height and width on the enclosing div & marking it overflow:hidden;

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I ended up using an additional slider.